# random high cpu load on linux box

Tags: linux, mysql, vps, cpu-usage

It was all working fine couple of days ago (never jumped above 3.0). But now, the load average for 1 minute jumps well above 10, may hit 20, and then goes back to 5-6, maybe 3.

The htop shows me that the most cpu-consumming process is mysql, but `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows nothing suspicious, and i have optimized all the queries.

The only problem that I'm worried about is disk space: i have only 4 GB left. Could that cause high cpu load? I can't imagine other problem.

`sar`:

```
10:24:52 PM       CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
10:24:53 PM       all     10.52      0.00      1.84     21.54      0.00     66.10
10:24:54 PM       all      1.28      0.00      0.26      4.28      0.00     94.19
10:24:55 PM       all      0.32      0.00      0.13      8.30      0.00     91.25
10:24:56 PM       all      6.28      0.00      1.24      3.07      0.00     89.40
10:24:57 PM       all      0.19      0.00      0.13      8.70      0.00     90.98
10:24:58 PM       all      0.59      0.00      0.20      5.14      0.00     94.08
10:24:59 PM       all      1.83      0.00      0.44      0.82      0.00     96.91
10:25:00 PM       all      1.50      0.00      0.59      1.63      0.00     96.29
10:25:01 PM       all      4.39      0.00      1.32      0.75      0.00     93.54
10:25:02 PM       all      4.88      0.00      0.95      4.63      0.00     89.54
10:25:03 PM       all      0.12      0.00      0.00      4.43      0.00     95.44
10:25:04 PM       all      0.06      0.00      0.06     16.30      0.00     83.57
10:25:05 PM       all      2.63      0.00      0.90      5.06      0.00     91.41
10:25:06 PM       all      3.44      0.00      1.10     11.34      0.00     84.13
10:25:07 PM       all      0.26      0.00      0.00     28.91      0.00     70.83
10:25:08 PM       all      1.23      0.00      0.61     20.03      0.00     78.13
10:25:09 PM       all      3.44      0.00      0.83     16.44      0.00     79.30
10:25:10 PM       all      7.79      0.00      1.47      2.27      0.00     88.47
10:25:11 PM       all      2.29      0.00      0.52      3.27      0.00     93.92
10:25:12 PM       all      0.19      0.00      0.06      8.81      0.00     90.94
10:25:13 PM       all      1.15      0.00      0.32      1.98      0.00     96.54
10:25:14 PM       all      0.76      0.00      0.38      7.38      0.00     91.48
10:25:15 PM       all      0.70      0.00      0.45      2.67      0.00     96.18
10:25:16 PM       all      1.50      0.00      0.61     30.74      0.00     67.14
10:25:17 PM       all      3.37      0.00      1.17     26.81      0.00     68.65
10:25:18 PM       all      3.27      0.00      0.96     26.83      0.00     68.93
10:25:19 PM       all     10.31      0.00      2.09     15.96      0.00     71.64
10:25:20 PM       all     10.23      0.00      2.47      5.55      0.00     81.75
10:25:21 PM       all     10.80      0.00      2.56      0.78      0.00     85.87
```

Comment: Check if mysql is swapping ... ? Also, check output of `free -m` ... ?

Comment: 1883 megs free of 2048

Comment: Do you optimize your tables (not the quries) on a regular basis?

Comment: yes i do. see my update

Comment: Do you see any swapping going on, when you run `free -m`... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its unable to suspect the disk space. You can enable all sets of logs in mysql, specially slow query log "log_slow_queries" will display queries that   taking long time to execute, to further monitor the mysql process through  logs.

There can be case like if your application gets huge requests and mysql unable to respond and waiting in the queue. So load average goes up.

You may find [1] useful.

[1] http://bit.ly/w2rPmz

Comment: no slow queries, the websites are stable, most likely it's not the mysql overhead that's causing high cpu loads

Comment: If its running on LAMP and if you feel there is huge traffic you may need to optimize the environment. unless causes sudden load average spikes.

Comment: well i already mentioned it's not the environment. under higher traffic loads it was running fine a couple of days ago (cpu load avg. always was below 3.0)